# Encoding in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

`NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCString:"Long dash symbol \xe2\x80\x94" encoding:(NSUTF8StringEncoding) ];`

`NSString *t = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Long dash symbol \xe2\x80\x94" ];`

Is there any difference between these two line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, both methods call

```
- (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes 
                       length:(NSUInteger)len 
                     encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```